# Going through script files and appending results to logfile

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that goes through 5 script files and executes them 
 using the contents of t1-5 as inputs and appends the outputs to a log file but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to increment a variable i representing the number of the t variables. Am I doing that right? And is this output redirection making sure that all the results are appended to the same file?

```
t1=`cat t1`
t2=`cat t2`
t3=`cat t3`
t4=`cat t4`
t5=`cat t5`

cd ..
cd tmp

i=1

for g in `ls`
do
    sh "$g" "t$i" > 0572log 
    i=$((i + 1)
done
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `i=$((i + 1)` should be `i=$((i + 1))`.

Second, `> 0572log` should be `>> 0572log` in order to append and not overwrite.

Third, if you expect to run the script more than once it would be best to put `0572log` somewhere else (e.g. `../0572log`), and not in your `tmp` directory. Otherwise, the next time you run the script it will try to execute `0572log`.

The quotes around `$g` and `t$i` are not required if you have simple file names without whitespace.

Comment: @shellter: I think that the OP wanted to execute the script files `"$g"` with with the shell `sh` and the parameter `t$i` rather than `cp $g t$i`, which would produce no output. Perhaps you meant `cat`?

Comment: ok, I didn't get that $g was another script. Yes you're right about cat.  Removing comments. Doah!